# Pandas row number for group results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to create a dataframe column that assigns a sequential number for each change in a combination of values.  Each combination of student and term represents a group.  My data looks like this.

| student | year |
| --- | --- |
| A | 20211 |
| A | 20222 |
| A | 20222 |
| A | 20225 |
| B | 20211 |
| B | 20211 |
| B | 20227 |
| C | 20211 |
| C | 20222 |
| C | 20229 |

And I want to assign values in a new column to indicate each unique student and year combination.  I've tried sort_values with groupby and cumcount but I'm getting a sequence of rows not just when the year value changes.  This is what I want

| student | year | enrollment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20211 | 1 |
| A | 20222 | 2 |
| A | 20222 | 2 |
| A | 20225 | 3 |
| B | 20211 | 1 |
| B | 20211 | 1 |
| B | 20227 | 2 |
| C | 20211 | 1 |
| C | 20222 | 2 |
| C | 20229 | 3 |

Comment: Based on your sample output, why can't you just take the last number off of `Year`? Or that is a coincidence?

Comment: Data is more complex.  This way just to simplify the example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pd.factorize` per student group:

```
df['enrollment'] = df.groupby('student')['year'] \
                     .transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0] + 1)
print(df)

# Output:
  student   year  enrollment
0       A  20211           1
1       A  20222           2
2       A  20222           2
3       A  20225           3
4       B  20211           1
5       B  20211           1
6       B  20227           2
7       C  20211           1
8       C  20222           2
9       C  20229           3
```

Comment: for more info, Factorize encodes the object as an enumerated type or categorical variable.

This method is helpful in obtaining a numeric representation of an array when all that matters is identifying distinct values